# Plotting 2 Graphs with Different Time Space

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe as below:

| Date | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-31 | 1 |  |
| 2018-02-28 | 2 |  |
| 2018-03-31 | 3 |  |
| 2018-04-30 | 4 |  |
| 2018-05-31 | 5 |  |
| 2018-06-30 | 6 |  |
| 2018-07-31 | 7 |  |
| 2018-08-31 | 8 | 5000 |
| 2018-09-30 | 9 |  |
| 2018-10-31 | 10 |  |
| 2018-11-30 | 11 |  |
| 2018-12-31 | 12 |  |
| 2019-01-31 | 13 |  |
| 2019-02-28 | 14 |  |
| 2019-03-31 | 15 |  |
| 2019-04-30 | 16 |  |
| 2019-05-31 | 17 |  |
| 2019-06-30 | 18 |  |
| 2019-07-31 | 19 |  |
| 2019-08-31 | 20 |  |
| 2019-09-30 | 21 | 10000 |
| 2019-10-31 | 22 |  |
| 2019-11-30 | 23 |  |
| 2019-12-31 | 24 |  |

Code for data frame is as follow

```
dti = pd.date_range("2018-01", periods=24, freq="M")
col1 = list(range(1,25))
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : dti, "col1": list(col1)})
df["col2"]= ""
df["col2"].loc[7] = 5000
df["col2"].loc[20] = 10000
```

This is basically a data where column 1 is showing a monthly data and column 2 is showing a yearly data (therefore 24 monthly data and 2 yearly data (data for 2018 = 5000 and data for 2019 = 10000)).

I am looking to plot this data by using 2 different y axis in a single graph since column 1 and column 2 are having large different scale. One chart is showing monthly movement and the other chart shows yearly movement where the yearly chart is simply a line that connect point 5000 and 1000.

My code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.Date, df.col1)
ax.plot(df.Date, df.col2)
ax.tick_params(labelrotation=45)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=(1, 7)))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
```

However, this does not work.